# Https on windows server 2008 iis works only on the server

Tags: iis-7, https, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall, connection-timeout

I have a strange problem on my windows 2008 server. I developed an ASP .NET application which I published in IIS 7 for http and everything was fine.

but then, I decided to add https support for my web site. So I followed tutorials and now i have a binding with a host header to my application in IIS for https. When I connect remotely to the server and enter my site, the https works. however, when I try to enter my site from my computer to the https page i get an error that "The connection has timed out".

I thought that it could be a problem with the firewall, but I entered the firewall settings and in "Allowed Programs", the "Secure World Wide Web Services (HTTPS)" flag is marked, and the flags for it's Private / Public are marked as well. So where is the problem?